# Can I select different .jar files in an XML .classpath file depending on what OS I am building for?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant

We are building a Java tool that runs on both Windows and Linux. The project is built in Eclipse. In the project we include The Standard Widget Toolkit (swt.jar). There are no common swt.jar file for both Windows and Linux, so we have to use different files, and this is what is causing the problem. Some developers are building on Windows and some on Linux, and to make it work the developer have to change the swt file to match the current building environment and this has to be done in a number of places. This is one of the `.classpath` files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/logviewer_common"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/logviewer/swt/linux_x64/swt.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="SWT_CONTAINER/PLATFORM"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Is there a way to add a condition that if I am building on Windows the file `/logviewer/swt/win64/swt.jar` is included and if I am building on Linux instead the file `/logviewer/swt/linux_x64/swt.jar` is included?

I have been trying to read and understand the XML tags and found that there is an <os> tag where one can specify Windows or Linux(unix), but it seems like I am not clever enough to understand if or how this can be used.

It is configured and built with Ant.

Would be very grateful for some help!

Comment: Does `maven profiles` help?

Comment: I don't think the .classpath supports an os tag, where did you see that? Probably not what you want but an Eclipse e4 RCP built with [tag:tycho] and [tag:maven] will build executables for all available platforms with the correct SWT.